# How to convert this in listfragment or fragment?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, fragment, android-listfragment

How to this code of **ListActivity** convert to **Fragment** or **ListFragment**. I wont to parse xml code to fragment to show parsed document on custom listview.

URL of xml document : http://apeiron.comyr.com/fit.xml

Code of application:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    //static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
    static final String URL = "http://apeiron.comyr.com/fit.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "novost"; // parent node
    //static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "naslov";
    static final String KEY_COST = "datum";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "text";
    static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
    static final String KEY_LINK1 = "link1";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        final XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, "Datum: " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
            map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
            map.put(KEY_LINK1, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK1));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);

        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_row,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                        R.id.naslov, R.id.novost, R.id.datum });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.naslov)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.datum)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.novost)).getText().toString();
                String link=KEY_LINK;
                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                in.putExtra(KEY_LINK, link);
                in.putExtra("link1", KEY_LINK1);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

What i need to do ?

I try this code ... but application is creshed :

```
import android.app.ListFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


/** This is a listfragment class */
public class AndroidFragment extends ListFragment {

    // All static variables
    //static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
    static final String URL = "http://apeiron.comyr.com/fit.xml";

    static final String KEY_ITEM = "novost";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "naslov";
    static final String KEY_COST = "datum";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "text";
    static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
    static final String KEY_LINK1 = "link1";



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
        //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, android_versions);
        //setListAdapter(adapter);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        final XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, "Datum: " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
            map.put(KEY_LINK, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
            map.put(KEY_LINK1, parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK1));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);

        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), menuItems,
                R.layout.list_row,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                        R.id.naslov, R.id.novost, R.id.datum });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.naslov)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.datum)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.novost)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                /*Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), Asd.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                in.putExtra(KEY_LINK, link);
                in.putExtra("link1", KEY_LINK1);
                startActivity(in);*/

            }
        });


        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
    //  getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);     
    }



}
```

LogCat:

```
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarnavtab/in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarnavtab.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5204)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarnavtab.XMLParser.getXmlFromUrl(XMLParser.java:46)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at in.wptrafficanalyzer.actionbarnavtab.AndroidFragment.onCreateView(AndroidFragment.java:50)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5117)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2272)
03-12 23:13:44.300: E/AndroidRuntime(3922):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should learn how to create a fragment and add it to your activity http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html . Then you will be able to understand how it works and move your code on a new class extending ListFragment.

If you need to be compatible < 4.0, take a look at the compatibility library http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Comment: I try but I not have lucky.

Comment: "Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" You need to put the long operations outside of the UI Thread. Take a look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: i need make new class with AsyncTask ?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html